# Docker image pull - received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to pull a docker image from our insecure private docker registry. But it fails with below given error.

**Environment:-**

```
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414
```

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "insecure-registries": ["private-registry:8080"]

}
```

**Problem:-**

```
$ docker pull private-registry:8080/docker/image/linux:1.1
Error response from daemon: received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Bad Gateway
```

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker.service
May 31 07:49:58 server-1 dockerd[3596]: time="2022-05-31T07:49:58.200818890+05:30" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get \"https://private-registry>
May 31 07:49:58 server-1 dockerd[3596]: time="2022-05-31T07:49:58.200866976+05:30" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get \">
May 31 07:49:58 server-1 dockerd[3596]: time="2022-05-31T07:49:58.208355568+05:30" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: receiv>
May 31 07:49:58 server-1 dockerd[3596]: time="2022-05-31T07:49:58.211891361+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/images/create returned error>
```

Any help will be appreciated to solve this problem. thanks!

Comment: That looks like a problem with your private repository, not something StackOverflow can help with. Unless other people are able to run this `docker pull` command successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after rebooting our docker private registry server.